# How to get count of youtube channel subscribers history data using Google api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-data-api, subscribe

I saw an interesting graph.

This graph shows subscriber changes from a year ago to the current day for a particular channel.

graph image here:
[image]

Graph images were captured at https://noxinfluencer.com

Is there a way to get the number of past subscribers for a channel??

Answer (score -1):

Nope, you can't get history fromYoutube APIs.
Websites like https://www.noxinfluencer.com/ ou socialblade.com have databases
regularly updated to provide that kind of graphs.